# variable changes value after while loop inside function

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with my function.

I have created a function that read out a table in DB and finds DISTINCT values from one column.

The 1st loop is to loop through the DISTINCT values
2nd loop is to get value from another column.

When I gather data from the second loop, everything seems fine, but when I try to echo the variable outside the loop, the value has changed to something I don't know where is coming from.

I am pretty new with PHP and can't find a solution anywhere.

Function:

```
function region_tilbehor() {
include '../db.php'; 
global $fdato;
global $tdato;

$query_tilbehor = "SELECT DISTINCT region FROM salg";
$result_tilbehor = mysqli_query($connect, $query_tilbehor);

while($row_tilbehor = mysqli_fetch_array($result_tilbehor)) {
    $region = $row_tilbehor['region'];

    $sql_tilbehor = "SELECT * FROM salg WHERE region='$region' AND kategori LIKE 'tilbehor' AND dato BETWEEN '$fdato' AND '$tdato'";
    $kjor_tilbehor = mysqli_query($connect, $sql_tilbehor);
    $qty = 0;
    while ($num = mysqli_fetch_array($kjor_tilbehor)) {
        $sum = $num['belop'];
        $qty += $sum;

    }
    $qty .= ", ";

    echo $qty; //gives this: 54726, 14313, 23689, 5885, 39783,
               //This is the value i want to return from function.

}
echo "same variable outside loop: " .$qty; //Gives this: same variable outside loop: 39783, 

return $qty;
}
```

Comment: post your code first

Comment: Please [edit] your question and share the code. It's impossible to help you without some more information.

Comment: Sorry. Forgot to add code. My bad. Code added now.

Comment: When echo $qty inside loop, it show the variable the right way. When echo $qty after loop (right above return), the value changes to something else.

Comment: Can you add comments on what output you get? And please note that you always reset your `$qty` to 0 on each main `while` iteration

Comment: Comments on both echo added.

Comment: Now that you added comment, your code acts as it should be. You echo `54726, `, then `14313, `, then `23689, `... always overwriting previous `$qty`

Comment: $qty is a variable and not an array, get the values in array and return it.

Comment: @Justinas: The $qty act like i want inside loops and echo inside loop is giving me what i want. Its when i echo $qty after loop, or return $qty, the value is all wrong.

Comment: @BILALMALIK Im am pretty fresh with PHP, can you show me an example of how to make an array out of this?

Comment: If you don’t know how to work with arrays yet, then you should go find yourself some beginner’s tutorials that explain the basics.

Comment: multiple ways. learn about array_push to start with

Comment: Try using SQL to produce simple totals `select region, sum(belop) from balg where kategori LIKE 'tilbehor' AND dato BETWEEN '$fdato' AND '$tdato' group by region` - although use prepared statements and pass the variables in as parameters and not use `global`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function region_tilbehor() {
include '../db.php'; 
global $fdato;
global $tdato;
$sumArray = [];
$query_tilbehor = "SELECT DISTINCT region FROM salg";
$result_tilbehor = mysqli_query($connect, $query_tilbehor);

while($row_tilbehor = mysqli_fetch_array($result_tilbehor)) {
    $region = $row_tilbehor['region'];

    $sql_tilbehor = "SELECT * FROM salg WHERE region='$region' AND kategori LIKE 'tilbehor' AND dato BETWEEN '$fdato' AND '$tdato'";
    $kjor_tilbehor = mysqli_query($connect, $sql_tilbehor);
    $qty = 0;
    while ($num = mysqli_fetch_array($kjor_tilbehor)) {
        $sum = $num['belop'];
        $qty += $sum;

    }
    $qty .= ", ";
    array_push($sumArray,$qty); 
    echo $qty; //gives this: 54726, 14313, 23689, 5885, 39783,
               //This is the value i want to return from function.

}
print_R($sumArray);die; //Gives this: same variable outside loop: 39783, 

return $qty;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Array gave me right values and i extracted the values out of the array after function.

Comment: @phingoc your most welcome